# JQuery: Loading dynamic content into dynamic div

Tags: jquery

To access a click event of a div that was created dynamically you use something like:

```
$(#divId).on('click', function() { });
```

What I am trying to do is access that dynamic div itself instead of its event. I want to grab some dynamic data and load it into that div. The problem is the data isn't loading since that div is created dynamically. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: No, that doesn't delegate the event.

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: @undefined That's not what is being asked

Comment: @billyonecan And I haven't posted any answer.

Comment: This is all very unspecific. Users shouldn't have to take shots in the dark to answer your question. Can you be a little more explicit in what you are trying to do and add some code for what you have tried?

Comment: @undefined I know you haven't, you just seemed to be quick to shoot the OP down about event delegation, when the question has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the div is loaded into the DOM you should be able to play with it.

```
 $('#divId').html(newContent); // should work
```

I assume the lack of quotes in your example there was an oversight.

Comment: Hi Bob. My code looks exactly like what you posted. I forgot to add in though that I show #divId as a modal popup, but I wouldn't see how that would affect anything - and yes you're right. The lack of quotations was indeed an oversight.

Comment: I do this all the time with dynamically loaded content. In your case the element must not actually be loaded at the time you are writing it.

Comment: You are correct Bob. My div hadn't been created yet at runtime so my jquery event couldn't find the div.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything more, it sounds like you may be trying to access the div using JQuery before the div is created and added to the DOM. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: If that was the case, I would have gotten a javascript error saying that the div element doesn't exist, but I am not getting any javascript errors at all.